# Is there any linux distro comes without ssh client by default?

Tags: linux, ssh

I have been asked what is the ssh client for Linux.

Does anyone know is there any Linux distro does not include ssh client in default installation.

Comment: I think you've been asked the *name* of the SSH client - which is typically OpenSSH. As for your actual question, I don't know if there's a distro that doesn't have an ssh client by default (otherwise I'd answer properly).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most Linux distributions have OpenSSH client today. Embedded Linux contain Dropbear SSH server and client.

Arch Linux comes without ssh client by default.